# jQuery code reload after submit

Tags: php, jquery, submit

I have a php page with jQuery, with range sliders. When the sliders are changed the jQuery code sums the values. This also happens when the page is loaded.

But after submitting, the same code (with other questions) also needs to function. The code works when the sliders are changed, but not when the page is reloaded after submit.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
function countSliders() {
    var SliderValue = parseInt($("#slider0").val()) + parseInt($("#slider1").val()) + parseInt($("#slider2").val());
    if (SliderValue == 10) $("#submit_next").button("enable");
    else $("#submit_next").button("disable");
    $("#lblsum_scores").text(SliderValue + "/10");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    countSliders();
    $("#sliders").change(function(){
        countSliders();
    });
});
```

Comment: Check for an error in the JavaScript console (through Chrome's console or Firebug in Firefox)

Comment: When the page is reloaded, do the sliders have their updated values set?

Comment: sliders is class name or id??

Comment: Start by cleaning up your code, adding radix to parseInt etc. like this [**example right here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hPjJS/1/), then check the console for errors. The two current answers below are'nt even in the ballpark!

Comment: You have 6 questions you have left unanswered, and you don't even thank anyone for helping. Might consider doing so?

Comment: ?? I absolutely thank people who provide usefull information. But some delete their answers or don't reply back.

Comment: Sliders is id (div). When the page is loaded, the sliders are set to 1 (or a setting from the DB) through php, which works fine. There are no  errors in the JavaScript console..

Answer (score 0):

use `<body onload="countSliders();">`

Edit 1 : where is your submit button mentioned at your question? if you have a `<form>` you can call `countSliders()` in `<form onsubmit='countSliders()'>`